# keep row if value in column is equal to another +5 max in pandas

Tags: pandas

Hel lo,

I have a df such as

```
col1 col2 col3
G1 2 2
G2 1 6
G3 2 20
G4 2 2
G5 1 100
G6 2 8
G7 2 4
```

I know how to keep only row were col2 == col3 with

```
tab2 = tab2[tab2['col2'] == tab2['col3']]
```

but how to say

tab2 = tab2[tab2['col2'] == till +5 tab2['col3']]

which mean that I can keep a row if in col1 the value is 1 and in col2 the value is 6 because 1+5 =6. 
here I should get:

```
col1 col2 col3
G1 2 2
G2 1 6
G4 2 2
G7 2 4
```

Comment: `df[df['col2']+5 >= df['col3']]`?

Comment: Have you tried `tab2[(tab2['col3'] - tab2['col2']) <= 5]`?